# how to equalize two columns of two tables, both having sysdate as value

Tags: oracle, plsql, sysdate

I need to compare two columns, both are having sysdate as the value but this

```
select count(*) from (
      (select col from tab1) 
       minus
      (select col from tab2 ) ) --
```

gives 1 , but I expect it to be 0

Let me further clarify :

```
create table tab1 (col date)
-- Can the datatype of `col` be something else 
-- rather than `date` so that when `SYSDATE` 
-- gets inserted to it, I get only `10-MAY-17` 
-- rather than the date along with time? 
-- I have control on this create statement, 
-- I can create the table as I wish to.

insert into tab1 values (sysdate) 
-- I have no control on this,
-- this is system generated .

create table tab2 (col date)  
-- I have control on it. 
-- I can modify it.

insert into tab2(col) values (sysdate) 
-- I have control on it to change it
```

Please let me know if the question is still not clear .
Thanks

Comment: What SQL backend are you using? Not every SQL implementation supports the MINUS operator. Oracle I know does, but SQL Server, PostgreSQL, and SQLite use the EXCEPT operator.

Comment: You are not being clear. What does the data type have to do with anything? Hopefully the two columns have DATE data type, and that should not be changed. What is the issue here? SYSDATE is inserted into tab1, and the same value should be inserted in tab2, but it's different because SYSDATE is called a fraction of a second later? Don't insert SYSDATE into tab2, insert the value from tab1.

Comment: @ShaneNal - Do you have a particular reason to believe the OP mis-tagged the post? I see Oracle and PLSQL, and the name SYSDATE which I believe is specific to Oracle. Why the doubt?

Comment: @mathguy Nope sorry I missed the oracle tag. My mistake.

Comment: Hi everyone .. Thanks for replying ! I have edited the question and  tried to provide more clarification .Could you all  please  have a look at the question and let me know if it is clear or some more clarification is needed .

Comment: If your inserts are a second before midnight and then a second (or more) after midnight then the value will still be inconsistent between the tables.

Comment: It's not the DML which is confusing. Whet we need to know is your business process. What purpose do these two tables serve? What is the business rule the MINUS query seeks to enforce?

Comment: Hi guys ..  I somehow found a way to modify the 'insert' statement of tab1 . so sysdate is not getting inserted now . So as of now problem is solved . Thanks for your responses !

Comment: APC wrote exactly what I would have. Why do you expect the two tables to have the same "dates"? As I said in my first Comment, 15 hours ago - if the requirement **is** that the two tables **must** have the same dates, don't insert the date into the second table via `sysdate`. Insert it via a `merge` statement, or some other similar technique that will guarantee the values are the same.

Answer (score -1):

The thing about `sysdate` is, that it returns the current date and time. When we compare one date column with another we are comparing the day and time elements. The columns will not match if the dates have different time elements.

I suspect this is why you are getting the result you don't want. Fortunately the solution is quite simple: use `trunc()` to remove the time element from the date.

```
SQL> select * from tab1;

COL 
-------------------
2017-05-09 03:25:45
2017-05-09 06:30:32
2017-05-09 12:20:47

SQL> select * from tab2;

COL 
-------------------
2017-05-09 14:12:10
2017-05-09 15:25:59

SQL> select count(*) from (
  2        (select trunc(col) from tab1) 
  3         minus
  4        (select trunc(col) from tab2)) 
  5  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

---

Alternate solution based on subsequent revision:

> `create table tab1 (col date)`
>   -- Can the datatype of `col` be something else
>   -- rather than `date` so that when `SYSDATE`
>   -- gets inserted to it, I get only `10-MAY-17`
>   -- rather than the date along with time?
>   -- I have control on this create statement,
>   -- I can create the table as I wish to

Build a trigger on `tab1`

```
create or replace trg_tab1
before insert or update on tab1
begin
    :new.col := trunc(:new.col);
end;
```

This will remove the time element from `col`.

> `insert into tab2(col) values (sysdate)`
>   -- I have control on it to change it

Simply apply the truncate when you insert

```
insert into tab2(col) values (trunc(sysdate))
```

Alternatively build a trigger on `tab2` like the one above.

Now you have records in both tables which have pure dates, so your original minus query will work without amendment.

---

**Note on the nature of guesswork**

My assumption regarding this question is that this is some form of process check: `tab1` represents some initial state, something happens and `tab2` is populated when the process completes. If so, perhaps the OP's query is meant to check that there are no unprocessed records.

Obviously we can think of better (more robust, more accurate) ways of implementing such a process but the question doesn't ask us for that. And yes I agree that Seekers should explain the business logic they are trying to implement rather than expecting us to reverse engineer it.

Comment: This will find the answer "zero" if `sysdate` was inserted in the first table three times today, at different times, and in the second table only once. The requirement is really unclear, but I suspect this behavior is not what is needed.

Comment: The broad point I am trying to make is that guessing at the requirement and providing a solution, when the requirement is not clear, is generally not very helpful. In this specific case I think it's quite a jump to assume the requirement was to match by `trunc(sysdate)`. In any case, the question - addressed to the OP - as to whether this is the requirement belongs in a Comment, in my opinion. Do you think it's likely this was, in fact, the requirement?

Comment: @mathguy  I agree with your sentiments 100%

Comment: Hi everyone ! thanks for replying . I have edited the question for more clarification . Please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: @mathguy - yes I do think that matching `trunc(sysdate)` is the solution. It's an assumption but not an unreasonable one, especially in light of OP's revision.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get 0 out of the query you wrote, you can use this:

```
create table tab1 (col date);
create table tab2 (col date);

insert all
  into tab1(col) values (sysdate)
  into tab1(col) values (sysdate)
SELECT * FROM dual;

  commit;
```

Further, the `minus` operator will give you rows that exist in tab1 and not in tab2. You would probably need to know the results the other way around as well. I nthat case use:

```
select count(*) (
select .. from tab1 minus select .. from tab2
union all
select .. from tab2 minus select .. from tab1)
```

This will show you the mismatches in both the tables, not only the first one.

Comment: Regarding the first insert the OP says "I have no control on this, this is system generated ". I think the two tables are some form of check, so the INSERT ALL solution probably won't help. But as the OP hasn't been back to this question since last week I doubt we'll get further clarification.

Comment: @APC - you might be correct as well, but in all cases I think that the insert all would fulfill the requirement .. dunno where this -1 vote came from, but it just seems unfair that you also got the same :( - that is negative votes, at least by the time I'm writing this ..